# Save 2 objects with a reference to each other in one transaction

Tags: magento-1.9, resource-model, transaction

for some security reasons I try to save 2 custom objects (different models) into the database, via:

```
try {
    $transaction = Mage::getResourceModel('core/transaction')
        ->addObject($object1)
        ->addObject($object2);
    $transaction->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem is, that the database table of *$object2* contains a reference id to *$object1*, but this is auto incremented in *$object1* and unknown at this point.

To visualize my problem:

database table of $object1:

```
 entity_id  |  ...  |  ...
 -----------------------------
 1234       |  ...  |  ...
```

the database table of $object2 should looks like this:

```
 entity_id  |  object_1_id  |  ...
 ---------------------------------
 5678       |  1234         |  ...
```

How can I get the auto incremented id of *$object1* and save within the same transaction to *$object2* table? Is it possible? Makes that sense?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a "one to many" relation here. `$object1` can have associated 0, 1, 2...,n instances of `$object` 2.
So you can say that `$object1` is a parent entity for `$object2`.
you can handle the save of both parent and child entities in the same transaction like this.

Let's say that the class (Model) for `$object1` is called `ParentObject` and the class (model) for `$object2` is `ChildObject`.

In `ParentObject` add this member:

```
protected $childObjects = array();
```

a method called `addChildObject`.

```
public function addChildObject(ChildObject $childObject)
{
    $this->childObjects[] = $childObject;
    return $this;
}
```

Magento has callbacks that are executed for each `save` method call from any model.
So you need to implement one of these methods called `_afterSave` in the `ParentObject` class. This one is called after saving the `ParentObject` instance, so you have an ID you can use.

```
protected function _afterSave()
{
    foreach ($this->childObjects as $childObject) 
    {
        //set the $object1Id (the FK value) for child objects and save them
        $childObject->setObject1Id($this->getId());
        $childObject->save();
    }
    return parent::_afterSave();
}
```

Now all you have to do in your code is:

```
$object1->addChildObject($object2);
$object1->save();
```

and everything will be saved in the same transaction.